# Ghostscript convert PDF to JPG (CMYK profile) resolution error

Tags: pdf, jpeg, resolution, ghostscript, cmyk

I'm using Ghostcript to convert some PDF files to JPG. All is working when converting the program consider the resolution of 600dpi when converting and output jpeg quality is good.

Here is my code :

```
 gs -sDEVICE=jpegcmyk -dTextAlphaBits=4 -r600 -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -o my_output_file.jpg my_input_file.pdf
```

But when I open the file in Photoshop, the properties contains **72dpi** instead of 600dpi I expected :

[image: 600dpi but RGB]

When I try with **RGB profile** for output, it is ok, I have got 600dpi.

[image: CMYK but 72dpi]

So what I want is **CMYK + 600dpi** in image properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen from your screenshots, both images are of the same dimensions, 6803 by 709 pixels.

And that is all that matters.

Also, the size of the CMYK version is bigger by about 33% compared to the RGB version -- as is to be expected for an image with 4 color channels instead of 3.

Ghostscript used the `-r600` CLI parameter to correctly expand the number of pixels when converting the PDF file.

Ghostscript does not add any EXIF metadata to its output when converting a PDF to raster.

The DPI or PPI information would be an internal metadata hint to tell any compliant viewers how big to render the image on screen. It would not change anything substantial in the image information itself.

Why Photoshop does think it should use 72 dpi for one, but 600 dpi for the other, you may ask Adobe about.

I bet Photoshop also renders the 72dpi file about 7 times larger on screen than the other. Is that the case?

---

**P.S.:** See also *["What DPI do web images need to be?"](https://daraskolnick.com/image-dpi-web/)*

Comment: I agree with your answer, but whn I insert my new file in my editorial system, I don't know if it will fit with his content. I need to try. I am reassured if that's the case. The ideal would be to be able to add information EXIF, is it possible with Ghostscript?

Comment: Only by writing code to extend the JPEG output device(s). Resolution is meaningless for bitmap images anyway. The resolution is simply the area covered by the image, divided by the number of pixels in each direction of the image. Any layout application will allow you to stretch/shrink an image, but all that usually does is change the area covered by the image. Thus the resolution changes, even though the image data is untouched.

Comment: @Meloman: You also could consider to post-process the Ghostscript-generated JPEG file with other command line tools (like *`exiftool`*, *`exiv2`*, *`exif`*, *`magick`* / ImageMagick v7, *`convert`* / ImageMagick v6), which could add the DPI setting to make Photoshop happy...

Comment: Good idea. Thanks